# Unlocking Imperial Marches Retail level after the event ends?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

There's no way I'm going to be able to get enough little medals or whatever to unlock this level in the next two days. I found out about it a little too late, and I've got all my Imperial levels working for me to get as much as I can, but it's just not going to happen.

I tried to roll back my device so that I'd get more time, and that also rolled back the timers on every pending order/task I had running by the same amount of days, plus I lost a bitizen out the airlock.

Does anyone know if the level will be unlockable in some other way after the event? If you didn't get Panna City from the decorating event, were you able to buy it later? Anyone got any ideas?

ETA: Okay, so I'm going to try something out, and I'll let you guys know how it works out or if it totally backfires since I have zero interest in buying bux to unlock a level.

I went and made sure I had NO pending orders or tasks, and THEN rolled back my device by 7 days. I then turned off application updates from the play store so that TDS would not update the program and screw me over. Today is supposed to be the last day for the event, but my game says I have eight days remaining and so far, so good.

Comment: This borders heavily on speculation, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't know of any way to get the Panna City Medicines level after having missed the December decoration event. My experience is that it still appears in the list of levels but the message when trying to build a new level is something like "no levels are available for your amount of progress." It's not clear what will happen with the new Imperial Marches level after the deadline. Presumably it will be similar to the Panna City Medicines as that is the closest thing that has happened to it.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat. (Playing under iOS on an iPhone 5, btw.) After making sure I had no pending tasks, I set my device date back by a week or so (i.e., closer to the start of the event). I did lose a bitizen out the airlock (worth the one-time sacrifice, I thought), but was then able to proceed by starting tasks on each level (usually the higher-medal tasks where available) and then advancing my device clock two hours — long enough for all of the tasks to complete — then repeating the process. Managed to unlock the droids (which all show up at once — I originally thought they were three *separate* rewards, but no) and Imperial Marches. (Note also that it appears that you only lose a bitizen when setting your clock *backward*, not forward. Kind of critical for this plan.)

Now I'm curious what will happen if I set my device back to during the decoration event — since I missed getting Panna City Medicines — but I suspect that since the app has been updated since, it probably won't work. Similarly, I'd suggest doing this *before* the Imperial Service event ends, just in case there's some kind of "flag" that goes off in the app once the event concludes that'll prevent you from going back after it ends.

*Update:* As I suspected, no luck on setting my device clock back to during the decoration event. Lost a bitizen out the airlock, but the device immediately triggered the end video for the service event, and no decoration event showed up. Fortunately, once I set my device back to the current date/time, the service event appeared to be back on. So you may have a few days (presumably until the next app update) to take advantage of the date-switch strategy.

Comment: To follow up on rolling my device back, I got an alert this morning that today was my last chance to complete the event, but my timer still shows 7 days left - this probably won't work out but was worth a shot.

Comment: I assume patch updates disabled the decoration event entirely? I haven't been rolling back and forth, only did that the one time since all the tasks were 5d pending.

I actually turned the application updates off, just as an extra precaution. Since I haven't even reached the droids reward yet, I'm no longer optimistic about the level now that I've gotten that alert :/

Comment: For those thinking about going down this route, if you have 16 imperial levels, you will earn about 50 medals per 90 minutes of game time, and there are 4,750 medals needed to complete the event if you haven't earned any.  You'll need to update your time about 90 times, earning about 50 medals each time, to get the level. Going the "natural" route you can earn up to 65 medals per hour if you manage all your imperial levels and build the most time-efficient medals possible (again, with 16 levels).  This will require 73 hours of in-game time, which means it can't be done before it ends now.

Comment: So you'll need to set your clock back by at least 135 hours, then build all medals, set the clock forward by 90 minutes, then collect and build again.

Comment: Yeah, the downside to this strategy is definitely that it'll be more than a bit tedious. I had managed to at least get partway through the droid reward level before I went "back in time," so to speak. And even then it was a lot of back-and-forth effort to get through. Kind of depends on how desperately you want the level. I was upset enough at missing Panna City Medicines (I had just started the game during the decoration event, so I didn't have enough levels to decorate for the reward) that it was worth my trying. Good luck!

Comment: Well, I did it anyway. Probably a silly use of my time.  Put device into airplane mode (no internet, cellular, etc), turned off location services (in case it used the GPS for time info - overkill), made sure nothing was in progress, then set the clock back 7 days. Started everything - 2 or 3 credit products, and each imperial build, then changed time forward two hours, collected everything, started everything, change time forward two hours, etc. My cycle time was about 3 minutes, and it took just shy of five hours with interruptions to go through the entire "week" of play, 2 "hours" at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough Bux saved up (or if you're willing to do an in-app purchase), you can use them to speed up the creation of Imperial items.  Anything that takes an hour or under to create will be created instantly for 1 Bux.  Over an hour takes 2, so to maximize the benefit of your Bux, pick one of the items that returns 3 medals (all of them take under an hour) and do it over and over again or you can watch the ones that return 4 or 5 (all of them take over an hour) and wait for their creation clocks to run down to 60 minutes, then spend 1 Bux to finish them off.

Answer (score 0):

Today I completed all the levels that were limited. It is May 5 2014. This is how it was accomplished. I did this a tedious way but it works. You can speed up the process if you feel like spending real money. I choose to take my time.

Step 1) complete all existing levels prior to doing these steps. So you know I did this starting with a brand new game. I set the clock back to Jan 1 2012. I am using an iPad. Turned off wifi. Built the levels quickly. At first advancing the clock one hour at a time. By the way if you start the game and get to the first imperial level before you set the clock back you will already have the salvage droids. Every day you advance you get another droid for free. These droids will give many items including bux. Payouts range 2, 5, 10, 15 when you get them. 
Step 2) as you build the Death Star make sure you move the people on the elevators. As recruiters show up fill up the apartments. Every slot. Swap out people as needed to get the star bitizens and earn more money. Remember empty apartment slots is bad. Every bitizen has a bday. As you move through the days you get free bux when you hit their bday. 
Step 3) after all floors are done you only have the limited ones to get. Suggestion here is set the clock to normal time. Then turn on wifi. Let the Death Star back up to online. Odds are you will be given a choice when restarting on the correct date. Choose the local Death Star and leave it playing for a while. That will back it up to the online automatically. If you choose online it will reset your Death Star. I learned the hard way. 
Step 4) set the clock to Dec 2 ( I will verify this date) at noon. This will set the holiday event to unlock panna medicines. Buy the decorator droids. To pay for the droids it will cost 60 buxs. Just keep ordering them and decorating. The floor and boba both show up. 
Step 5) set the clock to March 26th at noon. Repeat the same process. Order the droids and decorate. This one will cost you 300. But this floor is needed. It grants 15 medals at the cost of 2 bux
Step 6) set the clock to Feb 17th at noon. Instead of ordering droids. Go to the new imperial floor overbridge and order the medals. Only use this floor as it give the best bang for the bux. After 600 bux the floor and three black droids are yours. Deliver any of those droids to that floor to unlock the scene.